# Please help me understand the following java code

Tags: java, input, io

I am learning java from Java : Complete Reference.
I am currently working on the examples in the chapter : Input/Output : Exploring java.io
I dint understand few lines of code from the example below.
Can anyone help me with this example.

```
import java.io.*;

class FileInputStreamDemo
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
InputStream f = new FileInputStream("E://SomeRandomTextFile.txt");
System.out.println("Total available bytes : " + size = f.available());

int n = size/40;
System.out.println("First" + n + " bytes of file one read() at a time");

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
System.out.println((char) f.read());
}

System.out.println("\n Still available: "+ f.available());
System.out.println("Reading the text " + n + " with one read(b[])");
byte b[] = new byte[n];

if(f.read(b) != n)
{
System.err.println("coudn't read" + n + "bytes.");
}
System.out.println(new String(b,0,n));
}
```

**In the above code, I dint understand the last five lines of code.**

What is the outcome of

```
f.read(b)
```

What is

```
System.err
```

and

What is the outcome of

```
new String(b,0,n);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
if(f.read(b) != n)
```

It's a method call to read bytes from the file into the buffer. From javadoc:

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b.

This line:

```
new String(b,0,n);
```

creates a new `String` from the bytes inside the buffer `b`, starting from index 0 and taking the next n bytes. From javadoc:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes
>   using the platform's default charset.

And finally this:

```
System.err
```

returns a reference to the program standard error stream.

Comment: Ya Edited. Thank you for the answer.Your answer is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`f.read(b)` results in an integer of length 1, or a single byte.

`System.err` locates the error window and then places a message there, much like `System.out` locates the console window and then places a message there.

`new String(b,0,n)` will use the String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length)  constructor to make a string with the byte array b, starting at offset 0, and having a length of n.

Comment: well, here we have `read(byte[])` which stays for reading some number of bytes to buffer. it returns number of bytes read, or -1 if we have EOF or something else where stream returns no data.